# D3.js Focus+Context via Brushing Barchart - Recalculate BarWidth on Brushing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I some issue with a barchart with Focus+Context via Brushing. It's works pretty well but my problem is :

I calculate the barwidth with the bins and the width of my graph when I process my data.

```
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
            .bins(x.ticks(bins))
            (values);

var numBins = data.length;
var barWidth = parseInt((width)/numBins) - 1;
```

To be coherent, on brushing the barwidth on the focus graph should increase (currently it's keep the same width).  So I need to recalculate the barwidth. But i have no idea how can i do this...

```
function brushed() {

    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focusGraph.attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(d.x); });
    focusGraph.attr("width", barWidth); // How can I calculate new barwidth?

    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

}
```

Here the code :
http://jsfiddle.net/qcLp6qu8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution if can help somebody :)

http://jsfiddle.net/sx9myywh/

```
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  var b = x(data[1].x)-x(data[0].x);
  var w = b-2;
  focusGraph.attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(d.x); });
  focusGraph.attr("width", w);

  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
focusGraph.attr("width", width/(x.ticks().length));
```

x.ticks() will give the array of ticks, .length will give the number of ticks. To calculate the bar width. Total width by number of ticks this will give the space between the ticks which has to be bar width.

See update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcLp6qu8/2/)

Hope this will work for you, If not ask me for more...
Added a little code for better handling.

Comment: Thanks. But after some test :  your solution don't work when (with the brush) you select an little range or big range value. But when you take an intermediate range it looks like ok...